# JSQMessages TextForMessageBubbleTopLabel, swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I did some research about how to display sender name above the message bubbles on JSQMessage, but nothing is showing above the bubbles. Below is my code: the messages work fine, it is just the display name. Suggestions?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item];

    // Sent by me, skip
    if message.senderId == senderId {
        return nil;
    }

    // Same as previous sender, skip
    if indexPath.item > 0 {
        let previousMessage = messages[indexPath.item - 1];
        if previousMessage.senderId == message.senderId {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return NSAttributedString(string:message.senderId)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    // Sent by me, skip
    if message.senderId == senderId {
        return CGFloat(0.0);
    }

    // Same as previous sender, skip
    if indexPath.item > 0 {
        let previousMessage = messages[indexPath.item - 1];
        if previousMessage.senderId == message.senderId {
            return CGFloat(0.0);
        }
    }

    return kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct method signatures they should be the overridden methods from the library.

Change

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
```

to ->

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
```

and this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
```

to ->

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
```

Let me know if you need any more help.